# Smallest size of bit field

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, sizeof, bit-fields

I have some problems with understanding results returned by *sizeof*.

Let assume that I have two structs:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int  age    : 4;
    unsigned char gender : 1;
    unsigned int  size   : 2;
} child_t;

typedef struct{
    unsigned int  age    : 4;
    unsigned char gender : 1;
    unsigned int  size   : 2;
} __attribute__((packed)) child_t_packed;
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=10866c66fe82f4e4

Could you explain why the size of the first struct is 4 bytes?

Probably I am wrong, but I expected 2 bytes. (4 bits in the first row and 3 bits in the second row).

The packed version ignores alignment and in the second case *`sizeof(child_t_packed) = 1 byte.`*
Does it mean that 1 byte is the smallest size a variable of the type child_t_packed may occupy in memory? or the smallest value could be 7 bits?

Comment: Nothing can be smaller than a `char`, and I think the standard now demands that a `char` be at least eight bits wide. (The width of a "byte"  - and thus of `char` - depends on the hardware.)

Comment: That's right! ! thanks ;)

Comment: Ask your compiler vendor. The C and C++ standards do not impose any requirements on how much padding there is between bitfields.

Comment: @molbdnilo -- `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a `char`, and, since time immemorial (i.e., C99) the requirement has been that it must be at least 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard C++, the smallest possible size of a struct is 1 `char` (which is at least 8 bits). So even an extension like `__attribute__((packed))` is forced to yield a struct of size 1.

Furthermore, almost everything about the layout of bit-fields is implementation-defined.

In this example it seems GCC simply picks the alignment of the largest specified member type (`int`) for the bit-field alignment.

If you change `int` to `short`, then `sizeof(child_t)` will yield `2`:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned short age    : 4;
    unsigned char  gender : 1;
    unsigned short size   : 2;
} child_t;
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3db0b400312e3d2c

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it :( 
I understand how for regular struct sizeof is calculated. (see my comments) 
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/177768d48571f31f
How these 4 bytes are calculated?

Comment: The 4 comes from the type `int` which you used. In your case it seems `sizeof(int)` is 4, and types are generally aligned on their size. Thus a `struct` containing an `int` has the alignment requirement of 4. Which means it must also have a size which is a multiple of 4 (consider an array of those, for example).

Answer (score 4):

The size of `child_t` is four bytes because the implementation decides to align the `struct` same as `unsigned int`, which is the type of `age` and `size`.

> Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined. Bit-fields are packed into some addressable allocation unit.

See [`[class.bit]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit#1)

If `child_t` consisted only of `unsigned char` bit field members, then the alignment would be that of `unsigned char` and the whole `struct` would (most likely, it's still implementation-defined) fit into a single byte.

```cpp
typedef struct{
    unsigned char age     : 4;
    unsigned char gender  : 1;
    unsigned char size    : 2;
} child_t_char;
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/MGKPqGPKq

`child_t_packed` is of size `1` because we enforce minimal padding using the `packed` attribute.

> The `packed` attribute specifies that a structure member should have the smallest possible alignment—one bit for a bit-field and one byte otherwise, unless a larger value is specified with the aligned attribute. The attribute does not apply to non-member objects.

See [GCC 11 documentation on variable attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes)

Since 4+1+2 bits fit into a single byte, the size is `1`. This means that an object of type `child_t_packed` will occupy *exactly* one byte in memory.